# AWS Oracle RDS - Directory in external server

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, directory, external, rds

My situation:
- I have an AWS Oracle RDS
- I have a file in a local server

Target:
- In RDS I would like read (for example create an external table) the file in external server, using the directory.

I cannot create a directory like

```
create or replace directory TEST_DIR
  as '\\server\myfolder';
```

Because I have an error and, following the AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.Misc.html), I have to use rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.create_directory.

Unfortunately, this procedure create a directory inside the RDS, I cannot to point in my local server.

How can I do to create directories to read files in my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install Oracle Express edition on the local server.
- Create a   directory on the local server.
- Create external tables on the local server.
- Make a db link on AWS RDS to the local server.

  `select * from ext_table@local_server_dblink;`